# Rename the less frequent categories by "OTHER" python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter, categorical-data

In my dataframe I have some categorical columns with over 100 different categories. I want to rank the categories by the most frequent. I keep the first 9 most frequent categories and the less frequent categories rename them automatically by: OTHER

Example:

Here my df :

```
print(df)

    Employee_number                 Jobrol
0                 1        Sales Executive
1                 2     Research Scientist
2                 3  Laboratory Technician
3                 4        Sales Executive
4                 5     Research Scientist
5                 6  Laboratory Technician
6                 7        Sales Executive
7                 8     Research Scientist
8                 9  Laboratory Technician
9                10        Sales Executive
10               11     Research Scientist
11               12  Laboratory Technician
12               13        Sales Executive
13               14     Research Scientist
14               15  Laboratory Technician
15               16        Sales Executive
16               17     Research Scientist
17               18     Research Scientist
18               19                Manager
19               20        Human Resources
20               21        Sales Executive


valCount = df['Jobrol'].value_counts()

valCount

Sales Executive          7
Research Scientist       7
Laboratory Technician    5
Manager                  1
Human Resources          1
```

I keep the first 3 categories then I rename the rest by "OTHER", how should I proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: I have some NaN values ​​in my categories, if I do not want to rename them how should I do the filter ?

Comment: if i want to rename all categorical  < 2 value_counts, how should i do the filter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
need = df['Jobrol'].value_counts().index[:3]
df['Jobrol'] = np.where(df['Jobrol'].isin(need), df['Jobrol'], 'OTHER')

valCount = df['Jobrol'].value_counts()
print (valCount)
Research Scientist       7
Sales Executive          7
Laboratory Technician    5
OTHER                    2
Name: Jobrol, dtype: int64
```

Another solution:

```
N = 3
s = df['Jobrol'].value_counts()
valCount = s.iloc[:N].append(pd.Series(s.iloc[N:].sum(), index=['OTHER']))
print (valCount)
Research Scientist       7
Sales Executive          7
Laboratory Technician    5
OTHER                    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Even with this solution I'd  recommend converting to Categorical data. Otherwise, this solution isn't vectorised (`pd.Series.isin` with categoricals is with numeric data; otherwise with `object` dtype).

Comment: I have some NaN values ​​in my categories, if I do not want to rename them how should I do the filter ?

Comment: @IbD - Do you need remove `NaN` rows before apply solution?

Comment: I do not want to touch or remove the NaN values, I want to keep them.

Comment: @IbD - Function [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) by default exclude `NaN`s, so only solution is rename them by `need = df['Jobrol'].fillna('missing').value_counts()`

Comment: @IbD - Sorry, so you get difference between `df['Jobrol'].value_counts().dropna()` and `df['Jobrol'].value_counts()` ? Becuase after testing I get same output, because `value_counts` remove missing values. Check `df = pd.DataFrame({
         'Jobrol':[np.nan,5,4,5,5,np.nan],
})


print (df['Jobrol'].value_counts())
print (df['Jobrol'].value_counts().dropna())
`

Comment: So `others = df['Jobrol'].value_counts().dropna().index[3:]` solution from comment of another answer is wrong, because working same like `others = df['Jobrol'].value_counts().index[3:]`. Or something missing?

Comment: if i want to rename all categorical values < 2 value_counts, how should i do the filter ?

Comment: @IbD - Do you think top2 ? then change `.index[:3]` to `.index[:2]`

Comment: no top 2, i just want to select from a certain threshold : if value_counts() < 2 then rename the categorical value : "Other"

Comment: @IbD - Then use `s = df['Jobrol'].value_counts()` and
`df['Jobrol'] = np.where(df['Jobrol'].isin(s[s < 2]),  'OTHER', df['Jobrol'])`

Comment: @IbD - No tested, sorry. Need `s = df['Jobrol'].value_counts()` and `df['Jobrol'] = np.where(df['Jobrol'].isin(s.index[s < 2]), 'OTHER', df['Jobrol'])`

Comment: I am looking for a way to infer the "rare threshold" dynamically from the data rather than picking by ourselves like any frequency less than 0.05 (5%) should be clubbed into rare. That is the static number. Is there any way to get the threshold dynamically from the data to detect the rare categories? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Convert your series to categorical, extract categories whose counts are not in the top 3, add a new category e.g. `'Other'`, then replace the previously calculated categories:

```
df['Jobrol'] = df['Jobrol'].astype('category')

others = df['Jobrol'].value_counts().index[3:]
label = 'Other'

df['Jobrol'] = df['Jobrol'].cat.add_categories([label])
df['Jobrol'] = df['Jobrol'].replace(others, label)
```

**Note:** It's *tempting* to combine categories by renaming them via `df['Jobrol'].cat.rename_categories(dict.fromkeys(others, label))`, but this won't work as this will imply multiple identically labeled categories, which isn't possible.

---

The above solution can be adapted to filter by *count*. For example, to include only categories with a count of 1 you can define `others` as so:

```
counts = df['Jobrol'].value_counts()
others = counts[counts == 1].index
```

Comment: I have some NaN values ​​in my categories, if I do not want to rename them how should I do the filter ? Thanks

Comment: Something like `others = df['Jobrol'].value_counts().dropna().index[3:]`.

Comment: if i want to rename all categorical values < 2 value_counts, how should i do the filter ?

Comment: Upvoted as this is the most intuitive-to-read solution AND uses only Pandas

Answer (score 2):

One line solution:

```
limit = 500
df['Jobrol'] = df['Jobrol'].map({x[0]: x[0] if x[1] > limit else 'other' for x in dict(df['Jobrol'].value_counts()).items()})
```