# How to create "others" category in Pandas Column efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` like below:

```
print(df)

level   type

'xyz'     1
'abc'     2
'abc'     4
'abc'     3
'xyz'     3
'qwe'     2
'asd'     5
'poi'     1
```

I want to replace all the values from `level` column whose value count is less than 2 with new value `others`.

```
print(df['level'].value_counts())

abc    3
xyz    2
poi    1
qwe    1
asd    1
```

In above example the categories with count 1 i.e. `qwe, asd, poi` should be replaced by `others`

**Expected Output:**

```
    level   type
0   xyz     1
1   abc     2
2   abc     4
3   abc     3
4   xyz     3
5   others  2
6   others  5
7   others  1
```

**What I tried**

```
cats = []
x = dict(df['level'].value_counts())
for k,v in x.items():
    if v > 1:
        cats.append(k)

df['level'] = [j if j in cats else 'others' for i,j in df['level'].iteritems()]
```

The above code generates the expected output but it is too slow. So I am looking
for more efficient solution.

Comment: The marked duplicate should solve this problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53648445/9209546) has been updated to show you how to isolate categories with a count of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create boolean mask with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and filtered index values of `v` and set value by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
v = df['level'].value_counts() == 1
df.loc[df['level'].isin(v.index[v]), 'level'] = 'others'
print (df)
    level  type
0     xyz     1
1     abc     2
2     abc     4
3     abc     3
4     xyz     3
5  others     2
6  others     5
7  others     1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (v.index[v])
Index(['qwe', 'asd', 'poi'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to infer the "rare threshold" dynamically from the data rather than picking by ourselves like any frequency less than 0.05 (5%) should be clubbed into rare. That is the static number. Is there any way to get the threshold dynamically from the data to detect the rare categories? Thanks.

Comment: @AayushShah - So need percentage instead counts? Like `df['level'].value_counts(normalize=True) < 0.05` ?

Comment: Yes, using percentages normalizes the counts from 0 to 1. But still <0.05 is a "static" or handpicked number. I am looking for a "way" to get such a threshold dynamically from the data.

Comment: @AayushShah - Not understand, how are dynamic generate threshold?

Comment: All I mean is, each distribution of the dataset is different. The static threshold of 0.05 won't work all time. In some problems, your rare categories are those which have their contribution like 0.09, 0.07, 0.1, etc while in other cases the contribution will be different. Setting 0.05 (some other) threshold won't capture the general scenario.

Comment: The techiniques like IQR are may or may not work well with the frequencies. I was referring to [splunk](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.0.0/SearchReference/Anomalydetection?_ga=2.167175678.1588486002.1676954254-230496250.1672126561&_gac=1.48923220.1675421588.CjwKCAiA_vKeBhAdEiwAFb_nrbj8WwfEwzjlpNuodRoK6ea-eicPMibyXjdjq8OpWdbbWLQ0xNTuKRoCn48QAvD_BwE&_gl=1*yn43qk*_ga*MjMwNDk2MjUwLjE2NzIxMjY1NjE.*_ga_5EPM2P39FV*MTY3Njk1NDI1NC42LjEuMTY3Njk1NDM0OS41OS4wLjA.) they are giving 3 ways: histogram, IQR and zscore. Histogram seem promissing. But their documentation isn't covering the "how".