# Take nlargest 5 and sum/count the rest in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, count, series

My dataset looks like this:

```
ID   |    country
1    |    USA
2    |    USA
3    |    Zimbabwe
4    |    Germany
```

I do the following to take the name of the first country and its corresponding value. So in my case it would be:

```
df.groupby(['country']).country.value_counts().nlargest(5).index[0]
df.groupby(['country']).country.value_counts().nlargest(5)[0]
df.groupby(['country']).country.value_counts().nlargest(5).index[1]
df.groupby(['country']).country.value_counts().nlargest(5)[1]
etc.
```

and the output would be:

```
(USA), 388
(DEU), 245
etc.
```

And then I repeat it until I get the top 5 countries in my dataset.

However, how can I get a 'Other' or 'Rest' column whereby all other countries are lumped together. So countries like below are not so common in my dataset:

> Zimbabwe, Irak, Malaysia, Kenya, Australia etc.

So I would like a sixth value with output that would look like this:

(Other), 3728

How can I achieve this in pandas?

Comment: Related : [Python: Combining Low Frequency Factors/Category Counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418299/python-combining-low-frequency-factors-category-counts)

Comment: Related: [Rename the less frequent categories by “OTHER” python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53648208/9209546)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
N = 5
#get counts of column
s = df.country.value_counts()
#select top 5 values
out = s.iloc[:N]
#add sum of another values
out.loc['Other'] = s.iloc[N:].sum()
```

Last if need 2 column DataFrame:

```
df = out.reset_index()
df.columns=['country','count']
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace less frequent countries with `'Other'` *before* using `value_counts`. One efficient way to achieve this is via [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html). If you want to keep your original data, then you work with a copy, e.g. `new_country_series = df['country'].copy()`.

```
# convert series to categorical
df['country'] = df['country'].astype('category')

# extract labels
others = df['country'].value_counts().index[5:]
label = 'Other'

# apply new category label
df['country'] = df['country'].cat.add_categories([label])
df['country'] = df['country'].replace(others, label)
```

Then extract countries together with their counts:

```
for country, count in df['country'].value_counts():
    print(country, count)
```

Comment: I am getting an error with the for loop: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`